# CodeIgniter DB error, mysql join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have this query in codeigniter and it's not working...

Error: Unknown column 'forum_topics.category' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT * FROM (`forum_topics`)
JOIN `forum_categories` ON `forum_topics`.`category` = `forum_categories`.`id` 
WHERE `forum_categories`.`forum` = 1 LIMIT 10
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum_topics (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  user int(11) NOT NULL,
  date bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  text longtext NOT NULL,
  ` category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  status int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Query:

```
$select = $this->db->select('*')->from('forum_topics')->join('forum_categories', 
'forum_topics.category = forum_categories.id')->where('forum_categories.forum', 
$forum_id)->limit(10, $pag_start)->get();
```

I have searched all the internet, but not find a solution.

Thank you

Comment: Does forum_topics.category exist? If you posted your schema that would be somewhat obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a column called

```
` category`
```

this should be

```
`category`
```

or referenced as

```
`forum_topics`.` category`
```